# Cloudwatch and Cloudformation AWS

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

is it currently possible to set up a whole cloudwatch stack including the cloudwatch agent via cloudformation ? I cant find a proper documentation and asking myself if its even possible.

Comment: What excactly do you want to do? You can create Alarms and assign them with cloud formation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/use-cloudformation-template-to-create-cloudwatch-alarms.html

Comment: actually i need the cloudwatch agent to generate logfiles. the agent i already can install but i have problems to create policies for  the cloudwatch service and attach it to roles and the e2instances

Answer (score 2):

Yes these types are available in CloudFormation

- AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
- AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard

Additionally, detailed monitoring can be set in other resource types (for example AWS::EC2::Instance)

Installing the Cloudwatch log agent would be done by configuring it in the AMI or installing as an action in the user data script

Answer (score 0):

The following CloudFormation Resource creates a policy that will allow instances with this policy attached to their role to ship logs to CloudWatch:

```
    "CloudWatchLogsPolicy": {
        "Type" : "AWS::IAM::Policy",
        "Properties" : { 
            "PolicyDocument" : {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                            "logs:CreateLogStream",
                            "logs:PutLogEvents",
                            "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
                        ],
                        "Resource": arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:123456789012:log-group:my-log-group:*
                    }
                ]
                }
            ,
            "PolicyName" : "CWLogPolicy",
            "Roles": [{ "Ref": "IAMRole"}]
        },
        "DependsOn": ["IAMRole"]
    }
```

You will need to update the Resource ARN to match your region, account id and log group name.  The "Roles" and "DependsOn" assume there is an IAM role declared called "IAMRole" in the current stack.

When attaching a Role you have to use an AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile to create the link between the AWS::IAM::Role and the instance (or Autoscale group in my case).